# MOEA Framework - trouble with implementing method

Tags: java, eclipse, moea-framework

I am working with the MOEA Framework, and I am having a problem in implementing a solution method. I wrote the following code:

```
public Solution newSolution(double[] Cond) {
    Solution solution = new Solution(Input.General_Inputs.Num_Of_Ppes, Input.General_Inputs.Num_objectives, Input.General_Inputs.Num_Constraints);
    for (int Num = 0; Num < Input.General_Inputs.Num_Of_Ppes; Num++) {
        if (Cond[Num] > 3) {
            solution.setVariable(Num, EncodingUtils.newInt(0, Input.General_Inputs.Num_Alt_Decision_variable[Num]));
        }
    }

    return solution;
}
```

However, the method doesn't accept the Cond matrix as an input and I have the following error:  `The method newSolution(double[]) of type Optimization_Problem must override or implement a supertype method`

Any suggestions?

Comment: The real issue here is that your main class either extends something that's abstract or implements an interface, and its signature for `newSolution` differs from yours.  Could you provide the class declaration that you're using as well?

Comment: Thanks for replying I am thinking of adjust the Solution method in the org.moeaframework.core; to be like this public Solution(int numberOfVariables, int numberOfObjectives,
   int numberOfConstraints, double[] Cond) {
  variables = new Variable[numberOfVariables];
  objectives = new double[numberOfObjectives];
  constraints = new double[numberOfConstraints];
  attributes = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `newSolution` method as specified by the interface `Problem` [doesn't accept any arguments to it.](http://www.moeaframework.org/javadoc/org/moeaframework/core/Problem.html#newSolution())

It's difficult to say what you *should* do next, as I'm not sure of your use case, nor am I entirely familiar with the framework. There are two things you *could* do, though:

- Overload the method and provide a default pass-through value to your custom `newSolution` method:

  ```
  public Solution newSolution() {
      return newSolution(new double[]{0.0});
  }
  ```
- Instead of passing through the array, try instead to attach it to an instance of it and use that where you need to:

  ```
  private double[] condition;

  public void setCondition(double[] condition) {
      this.condition = condition;
  }

  // Here you can call your custom method with the parameter omitted
  // and rely only on the `condition` field.
  ```